# Problemas de estética con el tag "video" - HTML

Tags: html, css, html-video

Tengo un problema referente a la estética del tag `<video>` de HTML.

Este es el problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se ve una linea negra abajo del vídeo, se puede ver esto en los navegadores **Google Chrome** y **FireFox**, Así que no creo que este dañado mi navegador o algo así (No he probado en diferentes navegadores, solo en esos dos).

Estoy utilizando el framework VideoJS, para personalizar y cambiar la apariencia de el tag `<video>` y VideoJS no es el que provoca esta linea negra, porque puse el tag `<video>` sin utilizar VideoJS y aun aparecia esa linea negra.

¿Hay alguna manera de quitar esa linea negra?

---

HTML:

```
<video id="video-player" class="video-js vjs-16-9 vjs-big-play-centered" data-setup='{}' controls>
    <source src="{{ class.video.url }}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Aquí utilizo VideoJS:

```
<link href="{% static 'vendor/video-js/css/video-js.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{% static 'vendor/video-js/js/video.min.js' %}">
    var video_player = videojs('video-player', {fluid: true});
</script>
```

Comment: Agrega tu código por favor para tratar de reproducir tu problema

Comment: Ya actualice mi pregunta con el código.

Comment: Creo que esas lineas negras solo salen en los videos en formato mp4. Tenes dos formas de arreglarlo. Cambiando el formato, o metiendo el video dentro de un div apenas mas pequeño y con ``overflow:hidden``

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda!, lo soluciones con lo del `overflow:hidden` por ahora.

Comment: Por defecto la etiqueta ````video```` no posee estilos como los que muestras. Estos están siendo agregados por alguna de las librerías con las que estás trabajando.  

Para identificar exactamente que estilo es, puedes utilizar el inspector de elemento del navegador y ver las reglas aplicadas a la etiquetas y contenedores padres.
A simple vista podría pensar que se trata de un ````border-bottom````, el cual se puede solucionar sobrescribiendo la propiedad con ````border-bottom: 0px;````, aunque también puede ser un ````box-shadown````.

Comment: No es una librería o un estilo el que provoca esa linea negra. Para estar seguro puse la etiqueta vídeo a secas, sin estilos y sin utilizar la librería que mencione y aun así se veía esa linea negra.